# Evaluating bash enviroment variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What does the following line:

```
OUTPUT=${OUTPUT:-/tmp}
```

does? What's the value of `OUTPUT` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a form of [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) used for setting a default value. `${OUTPUT:-/tmp}` evaluates to the value of `$OUTPUT` if it is set and non-empty, but to `/tmp` otherwise.